# How to use return Redirect, inside View?

Tags: laravel

i have view page

```
@if((Voyager::can('delete_'.$dataType->name))||(Voyager::can('edit_'.$dataType->name))||(Voyager::can('browse_'.$dataType->name)))
 some function here
@elseif
```

return Redirect::to('404page')
@endif

error

> ErrorException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 156: Trying to get property
>   of non-object

else condition code is not working.How can i return inside from one to another.any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a redirect **response** in a view. A redirect response is a response with code 3XX. Response codes are part of the header, but you can only send the headers once. To send view data you need to have already sent the headers therefore you can no longer return a redirect response. You can however use JavaScript:

```
@if((Voyager::can('delete_'.$dataType->name))||(Voyager::can('edit_'.$dataType->name))||(Voyager::can('browse_'.$dataType->name)))
 some function here
@else
    <script> window.location.href = "{!! url()->to('404page') !!}"; </script>
@endif
```

Note that this will actually load the page and the user might prevent the redirect from happening so don't show anything restricted.

Ideally you'd need to return the redirect response before the view in the controller or middleware

Comment: thanks for the reply it's working but now its redirect to http://127.0.0.1:8000/404page.is there any way to redirect http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/404page

Comment: `url()->to(...)` can be used to redirect anywhere you want it to so you can do `url()->to('admin/404page')`. Also if it's a named route you can use `url()->route('name')` basically you can do whatever is mentioned in [URL Generation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/urls)

Answer (score 1):

Change `@elseif` to `@else`

```
@if((Voyager::can('delete_'.$dataType->name))||(Voyager::can('edit_'.$dataType->name))||(Voyager::can('browse_'.$dataType->name)))
    //
@else
    Redirect::to('404page')
@endif
```

And user [`redirect()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-redirect) instead of `Redirect::to`. Or if you want to send a user to 404 error page, use [`abort('404')`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-abort).

Comment: ErrorException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 156:
Trying to get property of non-object